# USB Request Permission action Broadcast not received

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, usb

I'm using the following code to get access to a USB Device on Android.

```
private final String ACTION_USB_PERMISSION = "com.myapp.USB_PERMISSION";

private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            log(Log.INFO, TAG, "on intent received >" + intent.getAction());
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                log(Log.INFO, TAG, "On receive for usb permission");
                synchronized (this) {
                    UsbDevice device = (UsbDevice) intent
                            .getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                            UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        log(Log.INFO, TAG, "Usb connection permission accepted");
                        //permission granted
                        if (device != null) {
                            log(Log.INFO, TAG, "usb connection devices");

                        } else {
                            log(Log.INFO, TAG, "No usb connection devices");
                        }
                    } else {
                        log(Log.INFO, TAG, "Usb connection permission denied");
                        UIHelper.showToastLong("Usb permission is needed to use the USB Device", activity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
};

UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
PendingIntent permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity, 0,
        new Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION), 0);
activity.registerReceiver(mUsbReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_USB_PERMISSION));
while (true) {
    if (!usbManager.hasPermission(usbDevice)) {
        usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent);
    } else {
        break;
    }
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works fine on Android 10. But doesn't work on Android 7.1.2

The Permission Request Pop Up keeps showing up over and over again and the `mUsbReceiver` is never triggered. What's the cause for this?

Answer (score 0):

- I think you should not use loop here. Try using the
  `usbManager.requestPermission(usbDevice, permissionIntent);` in the
  case where `UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED` is returned `false`.
- And also **unregister** the receiver in `onDestroy()` if you are registering it in `onCreate()` and unregister in `onPause()` if registered in `onResume()`.